# Execute Queries ServerSide with Flutter and Firebase rtDB

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I have a list of object in Firebase RealTime database, shaped like this:

```
-Places: 
    -BO-1232
         -lat: 23.000
         -lng: 45.000
    -EN-12323
         -lat: 23.000
         -lng: 45.000
    -FR-2323
         -lat: 23.000
         -lng: 45.000
```

And I need to Query all the items with BO in the name to get their lat and lng parameters: so, in this case, I would get only the first one. 
The way I did was I got all the Places child's and then filtered them after downloading in Flutter. The Problem with this method is that there are a lot of  items and downloading them:

- takes time
- weights on the device the user is using.
- currently will reach the firebase free account download limit (1GB)

So is there a way I could execute the filtering operation serverside instead of on the device in flutter? 
If this isn't possible or is much better done with Firestore, I could use Firestore, but I would prefer the Realtime Database.

Comment: Firebase does not provide such a feature, hence Flutter does not. What you can do is implement cloud functions on the server that take a query and return a result and you call that from Flutter. There is a Flutter plugin to call cloud functions.

Comment: "contains" or "LIKE" operation in SQL is a feature missing from both realtime database and firestore. Even if you executed the operation in cloud functions or other server options, it would still count towards your billing, so it's not an ideal option. Consider using Elastic Search or Algolia along firebase to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for all child nodes whose ID starts with `-BO`, you can use Firebase queries tocan order by the key, and then filter based on items that start with `-BO`.

In Flutter:

```
final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Places");
final query = ref.orderByKey().startAt("-BO").endAt("-BO\UF7FF");
query.onChildAdded.listen((event) {
  print(event.snapshot.key);
});
```